# troubeshooting why section of code becomes stuck in a loop

Tags: c, loops

This piece of code continually prints "Enter array value: Only numeric values can be entered" when a letter is entered. I don't understand why it doesn't just print once and the proceed to accept input. Ideally the user will re-enter either one or the whole set of values so using a break command which just exits the loop is not ideal. Any words of advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
 int i, value, containsValues[5];

 for(i=0; i<=4;) {
  printf("Enter array value: \n"); 

  if (scanf("%d", &value) !=1)
   { printf("Only numeric values can be entered \n");} 
  else 
   {containsValues[i] = value; 
    ++i;}
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Edit: Does the letter remain in the buffer resulting in this behavior? If so any tips for clearing the buffer?

Comment: Debug tip: print the content of variables  `i` and `value`. Also check the return of `scanf()`

Comment: thanks for the tip! But even when i increments the user cannot re-enter input anymore tips??

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the input buffer after a wrong input, use this `for` loop: it loops until the right value is entered

```
for (i = 0; i <= 4;) 
{
    printf("Enter array value: \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
    {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        continue;
    }
    containsValues[i] = value;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: thanks so much I realized my mistake and put a sneaky scanf in there to soak up the invalid input!!

Answer (score 0):

It entered endless loop because you don't break with an invalid input - index `i` was never increased.

Put a `break` for the invalid input:

```
if (scanf("%d", &value) !=1)
{ 
    printf("Only numeric values can be entered \n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: I've tried placing a break but that prevents further input as does changing where the increment to i occurs to in the for loop. Both stop the spamming but I would like the user to be able to re-enter the value